# Define numeric style properties (border-bottom-width, height, width and etc.) in react-native via styled components

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend, styled-components, mobile-development

I'm trying to build a react-native component using styled components. Here is the snippet

```
import { View } from 'react-native'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledPromocode = styled(View)`
  border-bottom-width: 1,
  borderColor: #CCCCCC,
  borderStyle: solid
`
```

But if I use this component in my render method I always get an error

> Invariant Violation: Invalid prop `borderBottomWidth` of type `string` 
>   supplied to `StyleSheet generated`, expected `number`.
>   StyleSheet generated: {
>     "borderBottomWidth": "1,",
>     "borderColor": "#CCCCCC,",
>     "borderStyle": "solid"
>   }

As you can see from the code above, border-bottom-width equals 1, which is a number value.

Do styled-components convert all values to a string under the hood?

I know that I can use StyleSheet.create to get what I need, but I also would like to know if there is any way to define properties like border-bottom-width, height, width and etc via styled-components.

If not, then does it mean that it doesn't make sense to use styled-components in react-native, because, obviously, errors like this would appear all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to separate your values with `;` instead of `,`.

Try this:

```
const StyledPromocode = styled(View)`
  border-bottom-width: 1;
  borderColor: #CCCCCC;
  borderStyle: solid;
`
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in more shorter way:

```
 const StyledPromocode = styled(View)`
   border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 `
```